# How to send json as a request in OptimizeToursRequest

Tags: google-cloud-platform

how to set the json as a request which I have in my local I only got protobuf method
I currently have json as request using it I am not able to send the request to optimize tours using client library

I was trying to send my local json as a request

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question and provide additional context and examples?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using google client library OptimizeToursRequest.Builder requestBuilder = OptimizeToursRequest.newBuilder(), and i send request using OptimizeToursResponse response = fleetRoutingClient.optimizeTours(requestBuilder.build());,  I am only able to send protobuf as request i want to send json as request when calling Optimize tours client